# Access front-end doesn't connect to my Azure sql server

Tags: azure, ms-access, azure-sql-database

I have recently split my Access database into a front-end and a back-end stored on Azure. It works from my computer. I added several IP addresses to the server's firewall so other users can access the database.

I created accounts with SQL Server Management Studio, and each one of them works on my computer: when I open the Access front-end, it asks for a log in and each account works.

However, I distributed the front-end to the desired users, but it doesn't work. They can't log in. I send them the link for a driver, but it doesn't work either: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

I am working remotely, so I can't help them face-to-face. It's also the first time that I have installed a server of any sort. I would greatly appreciate the community's help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you running SQL Server in an Azure VM, or are you running SQL Database service in Azure? If the latter: Have you added each of your users' IP addresses to the SQL Database server firewall to allow traffic from that machine?

Comment: Hi David! Thank you for your quick reply: I am running an SQL service in Azure. I have asked them to verify their IP again. Once, I distribute the front-end, they should simply be able to log in and get it working, right?

Comment: and if your clients are resolving dynamic IP?

Comment: @krishKM Hi! Thank you for your answer. I'm new to this, but I did some research. A computer is given a dynamic IP address by its internet provider, right? So, it's somewhat fixed, no? Moreover, how would the clients resolve their dynamic IP? I don't understand what "resolving" means. Thank you!

Comment: It means you should make your sql server accessible by any ip (if clients are getting dynamic ip). Or check whether they are having connectivity or  any other issues. "not working" could mean anything....

Comment: How would I make by SQL server accessible by any IP?

Comment: Be careful opening your database up to the entire internet.  See if you can get ranges of IP addresses from all your clients.  Generally you can get that information from your clients' Service providers and some creative searching.  But to answer your question to open your database to the whole internet, your IP range would be 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255.